# How to resize a shape in a flowchart while keeping the shape centred to keep arrows straight?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

Given the first sample visio flowchart. How can I resize the process box and have it stay centered for the arrows pointing down?

Currently I have to move the box back to the middle.

**Start Sample Diagram**

[image]

**Current Result**

[image]

**Desired Result**

[image]

Comment: I think high-lighting them all and clicking "Auto Align and Space" (on the Home tab, or alt-h,s) may be the quickest way.  A Ctrl-Shift resize combo would be nice though, eh?  Hopefully someone has a 'real' answer.

Comment: It does make my shapes fly out in an unreadable fashion. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Yeah, you can do sections at once (by highlighting specific objects), but it's pretty magical (and animated) so it may take a bit of use to get the hang of knowing what it will do each time. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the Size and Position window, select the shape, then enter a new width value.

Comment: I just tried this and it does work. Resizing using the attributes rather than dragging does keep the shape in the center. I was hoping for a mouse combination or visio setting to fix this.

Comment: Another option is to open the shape's shapesheet and set the cell Width = GUARD(TEXTWIDTH(TheText)). That will cause the shape to resize automatically to whatever text you enter.

Comment: To get to the **Size and Position** window: `View tab > Show group > Task Panes > Size & Position`